# Cannot connect to Access DB using pyodbc

Tags: ms-access, pyodbc

I've been beating my head against this for a few days now. I'm trying to use pyodbc to connect to a Microsoft Access DB, and I can't seem to get the connection string right or something. This is what I'm using:

`cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Path\to\file.accdb')`

I keep getting the error:

`Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')`

Even though when I run `dataSources()` I see:

`{'MS Access Database': 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)', 'dBASE Files': 'Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)', 'Excel Files': 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)'}`

Is there something I'm severely missing here?

Comment: There is a similar question that may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251702/how-to-connect-pyodbc-to-an-access-mdb-database-file

Comment: I'd already found that thread and tried all that it suggests. Still can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: It's helpful when you post a question after trying other SO solutions to point to them and explain why they didn't solve your problem.

Comment: I got the same exact error string as before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a 64-bitness problem. I solved it by using 32-bits python and pyodbc.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Provider=MSDASQL`.  It's [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811968) but it seems to work OK:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
DBQ=C:\Path\to\file.accdb; Provider=MSDASQL;')
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. Am I really missing something? I'm running Windows 7 Professional with Access 2007

Comment: It worked for me with Access XP (2002) connecting to an .mdb on Windows 7 Professional.  Since it is deprecated maybe it doesn't support the new .accdb format.

Comment: It also worked for me with Access 2007 connecting to an .accdb on Windows XP Professional.  I don't have a Win7 machine with Access 2007 installed, so I can't replicate your environment.

Comment: ok, I am really mystified now... Everything I try always gives me the same error string.

Comment: @SwimmingCode Do you have some solution to this question you posted without resorting on using 32-bit python and pyodbc? I am running exactly into the same problem.

Comment: Try this:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

I failed though because I have installed 32-bit Office. There is no 64bit driver for Access 2007 as it seems, so this may help you.