# Hand Install of 64-bit MS Access ODBC drivers when 32-bit Office is present

Tags: ms-access, 64-bit, odbc, registry, dllregistration

I want to do a hand install of the MS Access 64 bit odbc drivers.  Uninstalling 32 bit Office and installing 64 bit Office is not an option due to the add-ins that our company uses.

I downloaded the AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe and using WinRar and Universal Extractor have managed to unpack all the files into a temp directory.  I believe I have all of the files necessary but am a bit unsure where to go from here and would appreciate a little guidance.

Which DLLs need to be registered to make the MS Access ODBC drivers available in the 64 bit ODBC administrator?

Is there a list of registry entries that I will need to make for it to be available?

Has anyone else dealt with this in a reasonable manner?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Isn't there an installer for the 64-bit ACE?

Comment: Yes, there is, but the first thing it checks is to see whether 32-bit Office has been installed.  If it has, then the installer bails.  I have heard that the installer can be forced not to do the check, but am concerned that it could trash the 32-bit Office.  I'm hoping for a minimalist approach here.  Thx

Comment: Maybe there's a good reason for the installer refusing to go ahead -- from what I've read, you can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit Office components. Given that Office depends on the ACE, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

using the /passive switch you can install 64-bit ace drivers even if 32-bit ms office is present:
http://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/01/20/microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable/

Just be warned that installing the 2010 64-bit ACE engine on a machine with 2010 32-bit Office already installed CAN lead to some wacky behavior in your already existing Office 2010.

Comment: My computer restarted when I did this, so if you want to try this make sure you have saved your files in case it happens. Afterwards I tried it again and it seems to have worked (though my office is having a wacky behavior, but I can live with that for now)

Comment: Can you explain wacky? I am unable to start MS Access at all and Word is trying and failing to install something for half a minute before it starts so this does not look like an option to me.

Answer (score 5):

To install the Microsoft Access 2016 ODBC Driver, run the installer from the command line with the `/quiet` switch (which replaces the `/passive` switch from previous versions).

You'll also need to delete or rename the mso.dll registry value in the following registry key:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\FilesPaths

This information collected from the [Data Savvy blog](https://datasavvy.me/2017/07/20/installing-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-for-both-64-bit-and-32-bit-processing/).

Comment: After installing the 2016 edition of `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /quiet` on my machine, I don't see the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\FilesPaths` key in my registry at all - any idea? There's no `Common` key under `Office\14.0` at all, and the other `Common` keys elsewhere in the `Office` tree don't contain `FilesPaths`.

Comment: UPDATE: Ah, I found it under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\FilesPaths` - I needed to Refresh my Registry Editor view.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue with a SpringJDBC app that connected to an access DB when I ported it over to a win7x64 box running eclipse-4.3x64 Kepler.

What ended up working for me was to COMPLETELY remove 32bit Office2010 [ and Lync and other MS apps tied to this ] and install the 64bit versions.

Here's the really fun part:  The driver name to which you use for Access64bit driver name is now:

|**Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)**|

Yes, that's a comma-space after "mdb".

So, my spring-config for the Datasource looks like:

```
<bean id="dataSource"    
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    lazy-init="default" 
    autowire="default" 
    dependency-check="default">

    <property name="driverClassName" 
          value="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"/>

    <property name="url"        
          value="jdbc:odbc:;DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=/Data/dbs/cl97_2k.mdb;"/>       
          <!--  Above is Access 64bit Driver Reference  -->

          <!-- Below is the Access 32bit Driver Reference.        
          value="jdbc:odbc:;DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=/Data/dbs/cl97_2k.mdb;"/>
          -->

    <property name="username" value=""/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>

</bean>
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to install both without side effects on Office installation and without using /passive option. Downside is that is tested and working only on one Office version for now.  [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver for x64 app - how to make it work with x86 MS Office installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30666663/378783)