# Which version of the Microsoft Access ODBC Driver should I install?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odbc, ms-access-2010, pyodbc

I'm accessing a Microsoft Access database file via the [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) module. I'm running Python 2.7 (32 bit) under Windows 8 (64 bit) with a Microsoft Office installation (32 bit). So, I downloaded the Microsoft Access ODBC Driver **32-bit** from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). That works with my current stuff (Python 2 32 bit and Access 32 bit). But I also want to use the module from my Python 2.7 (64-bit) installation. So I download the Access Driver (64 bit), but when trying to install it, the wizard says that my Access instalation is 32 bit, so I can't procceed. And obviously, when running pyodbc under Python 2.7 (64 bit) the module isn't recognizing the driver, throwing this error:

> Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')

How can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know, that's what the installer says. What can I do?

Comment: Well, that are the options I already know, the 64-bit interpreter doesn't recognize the 32-bit driver. Thanks.

Comment: You can try installing the 32-bit interpreter (just be sure to call it manually via its full path in the command prompt as your default Python will still be the 64-bit one).

Comment: @cdonts Since you're wanting to use 64-bit Python, you're correct that you need a 64-bit Access driver. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116019/hand-install-of-64-bit-ms-access-odbc-drivers-when-32-bit-office-is-present) if you want to attempt a side by side install of 32 and 64-bit Access drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll check out that link.