# pyodbc and ms access 2010 connection error

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

How can I access my Microsoft Access 2010 database (accdb) with pyodbc?
Before, I used an mdb Database, which worked fine with the connection string being:

```
ODBC_CONN_STR = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=%s;' % ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE
```

Now I use:

```
import pyodbc
ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE = "PSA_TEST.accdb"
ODBC_CONN_STR = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' % ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE
conn = pyodbc.connect(ODBC_CONN_STR)
```

The error I get is:
    pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC-Treiber für Microsoft Access] Kein zulässiger Dateiname. (-1044) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Which translates to "the filename is not acceptable".
I found a related question, but the answer does not work for me ([Connecting to MS Access 2007 (.accdb) database using pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396429/connecting-to-ms-access-2007-accdb-database-using-pyodbc)). I use 32 bit python according to the output of:

```
python -c 'import struct; print struct.calcsize("P") * 8'
```

and MS Access 32 bit.

[EDIT]

- Just in case, I check with **os.path.isfile(ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE)** that the file actually exists
- the file can be opened with Access
- opening the previous mdb file with the new connection string gives the same error message, which afaik is not the expected behavior

Comment: Is the access database in your current working directory? If not you will need to give the path to the file as well as the filename.

Comment: Yes it is. The same code works properly with an mdb file in the same directory, and the slightly different connection string.

Comment: Actually, when I specify a wrong filename, I get the exact same error message. I checked if this is due to the underscore not being interpreted correctly, but changing the filename to test.accdb does not change the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, sorry to answer my own question, but by playing around, I learned that you need to specify the absolute path name if you use the second connection string:

```
ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE = 'C:\\path\\to\\PSA_TEST.accdb'
ODBC_CONN_STR = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' % ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE
```

Then it even works with the accdb file, as well as with the mdb file as expected.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your solution. There is nothing wrong with answering your own question.

Comment: for relative path we use      dbPath = os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent.parent, "datasets\CDR\CDR_Data.mdb")
    connection_string = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s' %dbPath+';'