# "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" with Access ODBC

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

**My Softwares:**

- Python 3.4 -64 bit
- PyODBC 64 bit
- MS office package Installed (32 bit)

**Problem:**

Now, I try to access MS Access 2010 installed in my computer using PYODBC. It does not work regardless of what I try. My error is always this:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

**I already looked at:**

[pyodbc and ms access 2010 connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806349/pyodbc-and-ms-access-2010-connection-error)

[Cannot connect to Access DB using pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548929/cannot-connect-to-access-db-using-pyodbc?rq=1)

It is suggested that it is 32-64 bit problem which I am sure it is. Is there some modification that can be done to make it work without installing 32 bit python and 32 bit pyodbc? I checked this website.[Using ODBC (32-bit and 64-bit) on 64-bit Windows](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/dataspace/owiki/wiki/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin) which explains about accessing the control panel to modify ODBC connnection and/or drivers. However, I don't know much about windows database connection internals to commence some changes.

Is there something that I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there some modification that can be done to make it work without installing 32 bit python and 32 bit pyodbc?

Not really. If you have 32-bit Office installed then you have the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE"), and only 32-bit applications can use it.

The installer for the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine will abort if it detects 32-bit Office components. There is a way to force the installer to continue, but that is not recommended because it can apparently break Office.

**Bottom Line:** The "bitness" of your application must match the "bitness" of the installed Access Database Engine. So, practically speaking, your options are

1. Use 32-bit Python and pyodbc, or
2. replace your 32-bit Office with the 64-bit version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried a lot yesterday thinking that I could tweak something in ODBC setup in windows but it won't work. Thus reluctantly, went and reinstalled everything in 32 bit versions.