# Connection to Access from Python

Tags: python, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect pyodbc to an Access (.mdb) Database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251702/how-to-connect-pyodbc-to-an-access-mdb-database-file)

I want to be connected to a database Boreas (Access) from Python. How to be connected from Python to Access database Northwind?

Answer (score 3):

Here are 2 ways, with COM dispatch and with odbc.  You will need the pywin32 extensions and/or pyodbc to use these methods.

```
import win32com.client
import pyodbc

def ado():
    '''
    connect with com dispatch objs
    '''
    conn = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
    DSN = ('PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE = ' + db +  ';')
    conn.Open(DSN)

    rs = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')
    strsql = "select * from deer"
    rs.Open(strsql, conn, 1, 3)
    t = rs.GetRows()
    conn.Close()
    return t

def odbc():
    '''
    connects with odbc
    '''        
    constr = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=' + db
    conn = pyodbc.connect(constr, autocommit=True)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    strsql = "select * from deer"
    cur.execute(strsql)
    t = list(cur)
    conn.close()
    return t

if __name__ == '__main__':

    db = 'c:/work/deer/deer.mdb'
    data1 = ado()
    data2 = odbc()
```

good luck,

Mike

Comment: @MikeHunter , at me gave out a mistake

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\ThirdTask\connect.py", line 1, in <module>
        import kinterbasdb, win32com.client
    ImportError: No module named win32com.client

Comment: @dva  You need Python for Windows extensions as Mike mentioned: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/