# Access Data base manipulation in Python

Tags: python, ms-access

I currently have an access database that has several tables within it. I am wondering if it is possible to extract individual tables and filter information from those tables using Python 3.6.

I apologize if this question has been asked previously, I am fairly new to programming and was unable to get a solution.

I have installed the pyodbc module if that helps.

Comment: There is great sample code leveraging pyodbc in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761236/connection-to-access-from-python

Comment: Thanks for the help! @James