# open access file in python

Tags: python, ms-access

I am not able to open the access file using python. I am not sure if the problem is with the mdb file or the python commands.

```
In [1]: import sys, subprocess

In [2]: DATABASE = 'Exam_BackUp.mdb'

In [3]: table_names = subprocess.Popen(["mdb-tables", "-1", DATABASE], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
Couldn't open database.
```

How do I know if the file is microsoft access file?
I have checked that mdbtools is installed on my Ubuntu server.

I need to open the (access or fortran) file and save the contents to csv.

Comment: You might be interested in my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25614063/2144390).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try opening it with an ODBC driver?

A good example is [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Database_Programming), reproducing it for your case would be along the lines of:

```
import pyodbc

DBfile = 'Exam_BackUp.mdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect('FILEDSN='+DBfile)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Do whatever you want with SQL selects, etc

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: @shantanuo A quick search here found this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251702/how-to-connect-pyodbc-to-an-access-mdb-database-file).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it by the Terminal using mdbtool like this:

Install `mdbtools` and upgrade it:

```
pip install mdbtools
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then look for the name of the table inside the mdb file:

```
home/Docs$ mdb-tables 'file.mdb'
```

And finally convert the file to .csv with this line:

```
home/Docs$ mdb-export 'file.mdb' 'name_of_table' > 'file.csv'
```